# How to create a logic hook in SugarCRM/SuiteCRM based on info in 'Campaign' subpanel of Leads?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a field in leads module as '`interested_c`' which is decimal type and would store numeric values.

Here is the detailview of Campaign subpanel of Leads Module.

[image: Leads Details View]

One record has Activity Type = Click-thru (iink) and corresponding 'related' which is a URL (tracker).

I want to create a logic hook for leads module, which if possibly, could use both pieces of information as conditions on each occuranc of:

`if Activity Type = Click-thru (link) and other 'related' = <urlxyz>`,
then the incremental value is add to custom field '`interested_c`'.

How such logic hook can be created?

There are some pieces of information which may be helpful:

1. This 'Campaign' Subpanel is getting most data from module: CampaignLog (which has a relationship with Campaign). [Corresponding MySQL Table: campaign_log]
2. These variables are defined in vardefs.php of suitecrm>modules>CampaignLog> [Vardefs of the fields concerned here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ouc9.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, and using the related field logic hook examples from `modules/Accounts/AccountsJjwg_MapsLogicHook.php`:

Create two files:

```
custom/modules/Leads/logic_hooks.php
custom/modules/Leads/LeadsLogicHooks.php
```

logic_hooks.php:

```
<?php
$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array = Array(); 
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(51, 'updateCounter',
'custom/modules/Leads/LeadsLogicHooks.php', 'LeadsLogicHooks', 'updateCounter'); 
?>
```

LeadsLogicHooks.php:

```
<?php
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not a valid Entry Point'); 
class LeadsLogicHooks{ 
 function updateCounter(&$focus, $event, $arguments){ 
  require_once('custom/modules/CampaignLog/CampaignLog.php');
  $campaigns = $bean->get_linked_beans('campaign', 'Campaign');
  foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {
   if ($campaign->activity_type == "Click-thruLink" && !empty($campaign->related_type)) {
          $focus->interested_c += 1;
   } #if 
  } #for 
 } #function 
} #class
```